# Find entry exit signal from time series data

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-series

I have a small time-series data :

```
ser = pd.Series([2,3,4,5,6,0,8,7,1,3,4,0,6,4,0,2,4,0,4,5,0,1,7,0,1,8,5,3,6])
```

let's say if we choose a threshold of 5 to enter the market and zero to exit

I am trying to write a program which will generate an output like this :

[image]

so far I have used numba but still working on logic can you please help.

```
@numba.vectorize 
def check_signal(x,t):
    if x >= t :
        y = 2
    if x < t :
        y =1 
    if x == 0:
        y = -1
    else :
        y = y
    return y
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use numba unless you had tens of millions of these samples?

```
states = ["Entered market", "inside market", "market exit", "outside market"]
state = 2
fout = open('seriesdata.csv','w')
print("Time,Percent_change,Signal,Timestamp", file=fout)
for pct in ser:
    stamp = ''
    if state == 1 and pct == 0:
        state = 2
        stamp = str(len(data)+1)
    elif state == 3 and pct >= 5:
        state = 0
        stamp = str(len(data)+1)
    else if state in (0, 2):
        state += 1
    print(''.join((str(pct), states[state], stamp)), file=fout)
```

If you'd rather make a dataframe, just accumulate those values in a list and convert after.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Tim , actually I have Dataframe with 24 million rows so I was trying to solve it with numba.

Comment: Then what is the point of this?  You can't possibly use human-readable data with 24 million rows.

Comment: With these markers on the time series I want to identify how many times the value exceeded the threshold i.e we can enter the market , once entered I want to remain in until a zero in encountered , once a zero is encountered it should be logged as the point of exit , then until the percent change remains below threshold we remain outside market and at the instance when it crosses the threshold it is logged as entered the market. In the end I want to be able to count the frequency of these events happening and their duration for different threshold.

Comment: So with a time series containing 24 million rows I can get a summary of these market enter exit cycles in the form of a data frame for different thresholds of percent change.

Comment: and what is the distribution of these events in terms of duration

Comment: Instead of human readable we can assign a numerical code as well